# java increment/decrement operator inside call

Tags: java, increment, quicksort

We're learning about quickSort.  The book provides the code at the end of my question.

I'm curious about this call at the end of the findPivot method:

```
swap(array, left++, right--);
```

Why have the "++" and "--" in there?  It's not incrementing/decrementing either variable (before or after the swap) and it's not accessing (for example) array[left + 1].

So what gives?

***EDIT***

So before I posted the question I wrote the following test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = 0;
    int b = 2;
    int[] array = {1,10,20,30};

    swap(array, a++,b--);

}

public static void swap(int[]array,int a, int b) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    Integer temp = array[a];
   array[a] = array[b];
   array[b] = temp;

    System.out.println("a = " + a + "\nb = " + b + "\narray a: " + array[a] + "\narray b: " + array[b]);
    }
```

The results are as follows:

a = 0
b = 2
array a: 20
array b: 1
a = 0
b = 2
array a: 1
array b: 20
a = 0
b = 2
array a: 20
array b: 1

The variable isn't post-incrementing at all when used in the method. That's why I asked the question.

Thanks.  Here's the code:

```
private static void swap(Integer[] array, int i, int j)
{

   Integer temp = array[i];
   array[i] = array[j];
   array[j] = temp;

}

public static void quickSort(Integer[] array, int left, int right)
{
    if(left < right)
    {
        int pivot = findPivot(array, left, right);
        quickSort(array, left, pivot - 1);
        quickSort(array, pivot + 1, right);
    }
}//quickSort

public static int findPivot(Integer[] array, int left, int right)
{
    int first = left++;
    while (left <= right)
    {
        while (left <= right && array[first].compareTo(array[left]) > 0)
        {
            left++;
        }
        while (left <= right && array[first].compareTo(array[right]) < 0)
        {
            right--;
        }
        if (left < right)
            swap(array, left++, right--);
    }
    swap(array, first, right);
    return right;
}
```

Comment: This is certainly unusual code. Where is this taken from?

Comment: It seems unnecessary condensed. There is a much clearer and less confusing way to do the same thing that has no loss in efficiency.

Comment: You mean like showing the increment/decrement in a separate line after the call?  If so then I freaking agree!  At one point today I was perfectly willing to concede that this algorithm works because magic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It are [post-increment (§15.14.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2) (`++`) and [post-decrement (§15.14.3)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.3) (`--`) operations. These will change the values for the next iteration in your while loop.

You basically have this:

```
while (left <= right)
{
    // ...
    if (left < right)
    {
        swap(array, left, right);
        left++;
        right--;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the "post" means that the values are not affected for that particular statement. After evaluating the post increment operation, it will the variable will be increased, but the value passed to the method was still the old one. For the advanced readers, you could write the post-increment operator like this (pseudo code):

```
public int operator this++()
{
    int temp = this;
    ++this; // regular pre-increment (JLS §15.15.1)
    return temp;
}
```

For a read about the pre-increment operator, you can check [JLS §15.15.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1).

Comment: This is the first time I have answered a question during the same second as someone else...

Comment: I'm not sure who was faster :/ I don't really know :)

Comment: I'll give you +1 for the code simplification, though :-)

Answer (score 6):

`swap(array, left++, right--);` is inside of a `while` loop, so the updated values will be used in the next loop iteration.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  In my test it wasn't incrementing/decrementing inside the method so I checked it in the main and they were both 1.  Thanks!  I'd upvote if I had the power!

Comment: @MayNotBe: Good! :-) Even though you can't upvote, you can (and should) accept one of the answers - but I suggest you accept Martijn Courteaux' answer, since his is more thorough.

Answer (score 1):

java increment(`++`) and decrement(`--`)
lets suppose `i++;` this means `i+1` and `i--` means `i-1`
in programming

```
int i = 1;
System.out.println("i : "+(i++)); // this means first print then add `1` into i;
//and
System.out.println("i : "+(++i)); // this means first add one and then print it;
// same for '--'
```

Answer (score 0):

They are  the  post increment (++) and post decrement (--) operation, so they  will change the values in the next iteration in your while loop

In your code at this line

```
   swap(array, left++, right--);//left++ , right-- are post increment (++) and post decrement (--) operation
```